# Prohibition on King's service?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras

I was reading shandilya bhakti sutras [here](https://ia600200.us.archive.org/34/items/Bibliotheca_Indica_Series/AphorismsOfSandilyaWithCommentaryOfSwapnesvaraenglish-EbCowell1878bis.pdf) PDF link!!  Came across this. On page 59, sutra/aphorism no 51

> And because of prohibition of gambling and the king's service. (51)
>
> We read in the dharmashastras that gambling and king's service is both prohibited;

Does anyone know which dharmashastra this is from?

[image: Screenshot of the page]

Comment: What is the context in which this was said?And it applies to whom in particular?It's better to add these info in ur Q as well..

Comment: @Rickross Context is that author of original sutra is saying bhakti should not be directed towards powerful personalities like kings etc.(Sutra 50) To support this statement he says because service of kings is prohibited. (Sutra 51) Commentator says this prohibition is in dharmashastras. My question is not about topic under discussion on that page (whom to worship and whom not to worship and why)  but to know which dharmashastras prohibit service to king. Anyway I have edited the question to add screenshot of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prohibition on gambling:**

> Manu smriti 9.221. **Gambling and betting let the king exclude from his
>   realm; those two vices cause the destruction of the kingdoms of
>   princes.**
>
> 9.222. **Gambling and betting amount to open theft**; the king shall always exert himself in suppressing both (of them).

**Prohibition on service of kings:**

> Manu Smriti 3.63. By low marriages, by omitting (the performance of) sacred rites, by neglecting the study of the Veda, and by irreverence towards
>   Brahmanas, (great) families sink low.
>
> 3.64. By (practising) handicrafts, by pecuniary transactions, by (begetting) children on Sudra females only, by (trading in) cows,
>   horses, and carriages, by (the pursuit of) agriculture and **by taking
>   service under a king,**
>
> 3.65. By sacrificing for men unworthy to offer sacrifices and by denying (the future rewards for good) works, **families**, deficient in
>   the (knowledge of the) Veda, **quickly perish**.

I hope this is what you are looking for.But even i am surprised to know  that service to king can be a prohibited act.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I was also surprised to read service to king is prohibited (for brahamanas?). I thought it would be in some obscure dharmashastra. I didn't even think of searching in manusmriti. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aks I am not sure if the verses apply only to the Brahmins..